# Cannot resolve symbol newRequestQueue - Volley

Tags: android, android-studio, android-volley

I have this bit of code in the MainActivity file:

```java
RequestQueue queue = new Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
```

and for some reason the `newRequestQueue` part is red and when I hover over it I get

```
Cannot resolve symbol 'newRequestQueue'
```

How can I solve this ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See https://developer.android.com/training/volley/requestqueue.html

Try it:

```
RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
```

Comment: Thank you. I rebuilt the project so many times and tried a lot of things .. This solved it.

Answer (score 2):

you just have to remove the `new` and it will be solved