# Gradle: Cannot resolve symbol RequestQueue

Tags: android, gradle, build.gradle, android-volley

I have added

```
implementation 'com.android.volley:volley:1.1.1'
```

I have also used

```
compile 'com.android.volley:volley:1.1.1'`
```

I did it in my **build.gradle** (Module:app) file.

I have added internet permissions in my Manifest.

Also, I have tried this solution ([Cannot resolve symbol 'RequestQueue'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34566999/cannot-resolve-symbol-requestqueue)), but it is not working.

Comment: Try with   `implementation 'dev.dworks.libs:volleyplus:0.1.4'` and `import com.android.volley.RequestQueue;`

Comment: for some reason that doesn't work either

Answer (score 0):

There are a few things you should check.

---

**Wrong** :

```java
import com.android.volley.Volley;
```

**Correct** :

```java
import com.android.volley.toolbox.Volley;
```

( [more info](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48386051/9298629) )

---

**Wrong** :

```java
RequestQueue queue = new Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
```

**Correct** :

```java
RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
```

( [more info](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33446747/9298629) )

---

**Deprecated** :

```java
compile 'com.android.volley:volley:1.1.1'`
```

**Recommended** :

```java
implementation 'com.android.volley:volley:1.1.1'
```

( [more info](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44407481/9298629) )